# How to find the shape of $x^3 + y^3 - 3xy = 0$ using polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus, curves, polar-coordinates

There is a curve known as the Folium of Descartes, and it has the equation $x^3 + y^3 - 3axy = 0$. I wanted to know whether it was possible to determine the shape of the case a = 1, using polar coordinates. I have only determined its polar coordinates representation, which is given by

$r = \frac{3 \sin \theta \cos \theta}{\sin^3 \theta + \cos^3 \theta}$

However, I am not too sure how to proceed from here. Do I use calculus or find the values at specific values of $\theta$, and if so, how? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you allowed to use a calculator (or trig tables) to approximate trig values? If so, then you should be able to get a sense of the shape by plotting values for $\theta$ for every $10$ degrees or so -- replacing $3\sin \theta \cos \theta$ with $\frac{3}{2}\sin 2\theta$ will reduce the arithmetic calculations. If not, then you might still get a sense (without a huge amount of work) by using 30-45-60 angle trig values (assuming you know rough decimal approximations for them, something in my time one tended to remember from heavy use of them) and some thought about trig function properties.

Comment: I also thought of something similar, but I thought maybe there is a more "elegant" method of solving this problem. Still, thanks for the help!

Comment: Yesterday I looked in some older (2nd half of 1800s) calculus books, and while [this curve appears quite often with many things shown about it (or asked to be shown in reader exercises)](https://www.google.com/search?q=curve+3axy&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1899&tbm=bks), including converting it to polar coordinates, not much was done directly from the polar equation. Finding the area of the loop is an example that was sometimes asked to find directly from the polar equation, although this was also done (sometimes in the same book) directly from cartesian equations.

Comment: Something useful working directly from the polar equation might be in the 20-page pamphlet [**Das Folium von Descartes**](https://books.google.com/books?id=RFVaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1) by Stanislaus Rychlicki (1884; also available [here](https://digital.ub.uni-duesseldorf.de/ulbdsp/periodical/titleinfo/7549220)). However, this is in German, which I can't read at all. There is some stuff on the 1st page that *might* be of use, but it seems to me that most everything after the 1st page is done using Cartesian equations and very occasionally with parametric equations.

Comment: Ah ok I see, I'll try looking into those links and see if anything can be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write $r^2$ in terms of $\sin 2\theta$, which shows some of the symmetries of the curve: $$(s^3+c^3)^2 = (s^2+c^2)^3 +2s^3c^3 - 3s^2c^2(s^2+c^2)$$so $$r^2=\dfrac{\tfrac{9}{4}\sin^2 2\theta}{1+\tfrac{1}{4}\sin^3 2\theta-\tfrac{3}{4}\sin^2 2\theta}=\dfrac{9\sin^2 2\theta}{4+\sin^3 2\theta-3\sin^2 2\theta}=\dfrac{9\sin^2 2\theta}{(1+\sin 2\theta)(2-\sin 2\theta)^2}.$$ But this curve just isn't very nice in polar co-ordinates: it's much nicer in co-ordinates $X=\dfrac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}$, $Y=\dfrac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then $$3Y^2=\frac{X^2(3-\sqrt{2}X)}{1+\sqrt{2}X}$$ or, if you don't care about scale, (replacing $Y$ with $3Y$, $X$ with $3\sqrt{2}X$), $$Y^2=\frac{2X^2(1-2X)}{1+6X}.$$

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Maybe polar coordinates just isn't the way to go for this curve. Thanks for the help!